# Calculation by, by means of, through, from

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences regarding the calculation of something should be preferred?

1. The calculation of the result **by** this equation...
2. The calculation of the result **by means of** this equation...
3. The calculation of the result **through** this equation...
4. The calculation of the result **from** this equation...

Moreover, is any of them particularly incorrect?

Comment: 2 and 3 are good. 1 and 4 sound awkward to me. 

option 4 says that the answer is already in the equation and you just have to look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of style, I would write "The calculation of the result *through the use of* this equation".  Alternatively I would suggest *by the use of*.

The correctness of choosing *by*, *by means of*, *through*, or *from* depend on whether *this equation* is thought of as a tool, a route to a result, or a process that generates a result.  The choice of the phrase *through the use of* avoids any ambiguity about the nature of *equation* because it is equally applicable to all of those meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Although not incorrect, probably none of those sentences is common in mathematics. More common choices are:

1. This equation yields... / The above equation yields... / Equation (1) yields... (in the case of numbered equations)
2. From this equation one obtains/we obtain... / From the above equation one obtains/we obtain... / From (1) one obtains/we obtain
3. By plugging the values into ..., one gets/we get

Answer (score -1):

How about, "solving this equation," or "calculating the result of this equation," or "the calculation of the solution to this equation?"